# how to count frequency of a word present in hashtable using java

Tags: java, collections, hashtable

I have a small assignment, where I have a in Hashtable format. Now I want to find a number of times a word is present in that.

Kindly guide me in this.
thanks
**Edit#1**

```
Hashtable<String, Integer> h = new Hashtable<String, Integer>();
```

**Edit #2**

```
if(spam.containsKey(s)){
                                  int value = spam.get(s);
                                  value += 1;
                                  spam.put(s,value);
                              }else{
                                  spam.put(s,1);
                              }
```

Ok, I changed my code to this now. I will have the count of that word as a value.

Comment: Can you show us code how this `HashTable` is constructed? I assume the words are the values of the key-value pairs in the table.

Comment: @mad_programmer - I think you're going to have to clarify, because if the words are the keys, they are unique since `HashTable` has unique keys (i.e. each key only occurs once in a `HashTable`).

Comment: Do you just want to get the `Integer` value back from a `String` in your `Hashtable h`?

Comment: So what the problem with your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common assignment is to use a hash-table like the one you show for a slightly different problem: to find the word-frequencies in a section of text (typically given as a String). Are you perhaps confused by the wording of the assignment?

If my hypothesis is correct, then here is a small hint: you have to fill the hash table in such a way that the hash maps words (the keys in the hash table) to the frequence with which they occur in the text.

Answer (score 4):

You will always have 0 or 1 occurrences of a specific word since a Hashtable does not allow key duplicates.

If you do h.add("hi",1) and then h.add("hi",2) and then you do n = h.get("hi") you will get 2.
And h will contain just one "hi" string as key.